# Example of a simple web project using ES6 with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

Right now I am building frontend assets for my php cms projects using gulp. I split javascript into multiple files and concatenate them with a thing called [rigger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rigger), but could easily do the same with gulp-concat.

I am trying to move to webpack workflow with ES6 modules now. I look for a good example, but all the ones I can find are way too complicated. None of them use jQuery and simple jQuery plugins like lightbox, carousel and such.

Please suggest a good example of a small web project (preferably a github repo) that has simple javascript partials baked as ES6 modules.

Comment: the webpacks own website: https://webpack.js.org/guides/ offers a pretty good amount of guides, you probably would like to check them out, moving from gulp to webpack isnt a big step, but it isnt seamless either...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have spent quite some time reading through these and alike. But I could not find an example simple enough and close to my type of projects. Everybody seem to use some kind of framework. But my partials-to-be-modules are just some trivial jQuery stuff that query dom and initialize jQuery plugins. I got a partial for popups, slider, gallery and a form... Maybe this type of code is not even supposed to be put in modules) Anyway, no examples found, and that is the reason for a question/